# Variables se concatenan en lugar de sumarse

Tags: vb.net

Estoy realizando una solucion en Visual Studio 2017 que emula un tipo de factura simple, el usuario ingresa los valores a traves de un textbox, le da en el boton "Agregar" y los datos se ingresan en un Data Grid View, despues al presionar el boton "Calcular" se calcula el importe total, el iva de ese importe y luego el total de la suma del importe y el IVA. 
El problema radica en que el calculo del total(importe + IVA), no se suma, solo se imprimen ambos valores concatenados. Por que podria estar pasando esto?

Este es mi codigo:

```
    Public Class Form1
Dim importePR As Double

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    importePR = txtcantidad.Text * txtprecio.Text
    Me.DGV1.Rows.Add(txtdescrip.Text, txtcantidad.Text, txtprecio.Text, importePR)
    txtdescrip.Clear()
    txtcantidad.Clear()
    txtprecio.Clear()



End Sub


Private Sub btnBorrar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBorrar.Click

    DGV1.Rows.Clear()


    txtdescrip.Clear()
    txtcantidad.Clear()
    txtprecio.Clear()
    txtimporte.Clear()
    txtIVA.Clear()
    txttotal.Clear()

    txtdescrip.Text = " "
    txtcantidad.Text = " "
    txtprecio.Text = " "




End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DGV1.CellContentClick




End Sub

Private Sub btnCalcular_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalcular.Click
    Dim importe As Double
    Dim ImpTotal As Double
    Dim fila As DataGridViewRow = New DataGridViewRow()

    For Each fila In DGV1.Rows
        importe += Convert.ToDouble(fila.Cells("Importe").Value)

    Next

    txtimporte.Text = Convert.ToString(importe)

    txtIVA.Text = txtimporte.Text * 0.16

    ImpTotal = txtimporte.Text + txtIVA.Text
    txttotal.Text = ImpTotal

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Visual studio es la ide donde estas programando, y no tiene nada que ver con el problema. Tu problema es el lenguaje ;)

Comment: Si ok. El lenguaje es Visul Basic .NET

Answer (score 1):

El simbolo `+` sirve de varias manera, en caso de ser enteros los suma 
Ej:

```
dim x as int = 1
dim y as int = 2
dim z as int = x + y

Msgbox(z) 'En el MessageBox aparecera el numero 3
```

Ahora si en vez de ser enteros son Strings (Cadenas de texto)

```
   Dim str2 As String = "ho"
    Dim str1 As String = "la"
    Dim z As String = str2 + str1

    MsgBox(z)'en el msgbox aparecera hola
```

Si no definimos primero que tipo de informacion contiene el textbox estos errores pasaran seguido. Tu solucion es esta:

`ImpTotal = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Texttxtimporte.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(txtIVA.Text)`

Pero para un correcto funcionamiento de las cosas deberias hacer esto

```
    Dim intImporte As Integer = Importe.Text 'Definimos la variable de tipo entero con el nombre intImporte y le ponemos dentro el valor de el importe.text
    Dim intIva As Integer = Iva.Text 'Definimos la variable de tipo entero con el nombre intImporte y le ponemos dentro el valor de el importe.text
    Dim intImpTotal as integer = IntImporte + IntIva 'Sumamos las dos variables 
    ImpTotal.text = intImpTotal 'Ingresamos en el textbox el resultado de las sumas.
```

Yapa:
Si necesitas ingresar cadenas de texto a un entero hazlo con el simbolo `&`
Ej:

```
'Imaginemos que imtImptotal vale 1500
     ImpTotal.text = "$" & intImpTotal ' Devuelve $1500
```

Saludos y buen código.

Answer (score 0):

Esto pasa simplemente porque el operador `+` esta sobrecargado en VB.

Por lo tanto, funciona distinto dependiendo el tipo de objetos que tiene que "sumar"

En tu caso, estas sumando dos `strings`, por lo tanto, el operador `+` no suma su contenido, si no que lo concatena, haciendo que las cadenas se "sumen" una al lado de la otra.

Para obtener la suma de dos números, pero que están contenidos en variables de tipo `string` (y la propiedad `text` de un `textbox`, es justamente un string), lo que tenes que hacer es convertirlo a entero.

Para eso hay varios metodos, pero suponiendo que tus textbox sean correctos, podes usar `Int32.Parse()`.

Recuerda controlar que los valores sean correctos, si no Parse va a tirar una excepcion. Para controlar, podes usar `Int32.TryParse()`.

Comment: Esta trabajando con precios por lo que debe convertir a decimal. En VB si no me equivoco es así: `Convert.toDecimal(txtPrice.Text)`

Answer (score 0):

Activa el Control de Errores y no lo Analices, Para el Problema de la Suma, se Tiene que Hacer la Suma Con los Strings Convertidos a Integers...

Prueba con este código rectificado...

```html
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    importePR = txtcantidad.Text * txtprecio.Text
    Me.DGV1.Rows.Add(txtdescrip.Text, txtcantidad.Text, txtprecio.Text, importePR)
    txtdescrip.Clear()
    txtcantidad.Clear()
    txtprecio.Clear()



End Sub


Private Sub btnBorrar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBorrar.Click

    DGV1.Rows.Clear()


    txtdescrip.Clear()
    txtcantidad.Clear()
    txtprecio.Clear()
    txtimporte.Clear()
    txtIVA.Clear()
    txttotal.Clear()

    txtdescrip.Text = " "
    txtcantidad.Text = "1"
    txtprecio.Text = "0.00"




End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DGV1.CellContentClick




End Sub

Private Sub btnCalcular_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalcular.Click
On Error Resume Next
    Dim importe As Double
    Dim ImpTotal As Double
    Dim fila As DataGridViewRow = New DataGridViewRow()

    For Each fila In DGV1.Rows
        importe += Convert.ToDouble(fila.Cells("Importe").Value)

    Next

    txtimporte.Text = Convert.ToString(importe)

    txtIVA.Text = CDbl(txtimporte.Text) * 0.16

    ImpTotal = CDbl(txtimporte.Text) + CDbl(txtIVA.Text)
    txttotal.Text = ImpTotal

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Estás sumando variables de tipo texto, como el contenido de un textbox. Tienes que antes de sumar com +, convertirlas a numeros, como double, inter, etc, con las funciones que tiene el VB para esto, como CINT() etc.

De ahí ya puedes sumar tranquilamente.